# Loopback unable to create and do operations on related models in model JS file

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Unable to create relation in model.js file while through model.json file, it's working fine. I want to update booking table field on any updation in bidding table but my relation is not working in model.js file.

Bidding.belongsTo(Booking, {foreignKey: 'bookingId'});
                          ^
    ReferenceError: Booking is not defined

```js
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Bidding.booking is not a function",
    "stack": "TypeError: Bidding.booking is not a function\n.."
  }
}
```

```js
'use strict';


 //var loopback = require('loopback');
//var boot = require('loopback-boot');

//var app = module.exports = loopback();

module.exports = function(Bidding) {

   // var app = require('../../server/server'); 
    // var Booking = app.models.Booking;
    //Bidding.belongsTo(Myuser, {foreignKey: 'driver_id'});

    Bidding.belongsTo(Booking, {foreignKey: 'bookingId'});

    Bidding.observe('before save', function beforeSave(ctx, next) {
                if (ctx.instance) {

                   //on create
                   ctx.instance.created = new Date();
                   ctx.instance.modified = new Date();

                } else {
                   // on edit
                // ctx.instance.lastUpdated = new Date();
                console.log('updatesdd');
                //Bidding.Booking.upsertWithWhere({id: ctx.instance.id},{ 'username': username}, function(err, results) {});
                Bidding.booking(function(err, booking) {
                 
                         console.log(ctx.booking);      
                     });
                }

               
                next();
            });

        Bidding.observe('loaded', function beforeaccess(ctx, next) {

           console.log(ctx.data);


               
                next();
            });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

By following way you can perform the operations on your relates tables. I go through inbuilt user.js file where they have relation with AccessToken table and find the following solution for my problem.

Query which load you related table -

Here "booking" model has belongs to relation define in bidding.json
 var booking = ctx.Model.relations.booking.modelTo;

Update Query call through StrongLoop API Explorer:

http://0.0.0.0/api/Biddings/update?where=%7B%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22bookingId%22%3A6%7D

Where: {"id":"11","bookingId":6}
data: {"bid_status":"Accept"}

```js
Bidding.observe('before save', function beforeSave(ctx, next) {
                

                if (ctx.instance) {

                   //on create
                   ctx.instance.created = new Date();
                   ctx.instance.modified = new Date();

                } else {

                      //on update
                      if(ctx.data.bid_status == "Accept");
                      {

                        if (ctx.where && ctx.where.bookingId && ctx.where.id) {

                          var bookingId  = ctx.where.bookingId;
                          var booking = ctx.Model.relations.booking.modelTo;
                          booking.upsertWithWhere({id: bookingId},{ 'booking_status': 'Confirmed'}, function(err, results) {});
                        
                        }
                       
                       }
             
                }

               
                next();
            });
```